# Create a Module for prestashop 8.1.1

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-modules

I want to make a module in prestashop 8.1 that creates a new field at the time of registration and at the time of payment without login send this information to the database in a column in the Customers table and finally show the value that is in this column in the customer information in the backoffice

i try to make it by some tutorials and reading the documentation but its doesnt work (sorry for bad english)

v1:

```
<?php 

if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_')) {
    exit;
}
class Cpf extends Module{
    public function __construct() {
        
            $this->name = 'cpf';
            $this->tab = 'front_office_features';
            $this->version = '1.0.4.2';
            $this->author = 'Henrique Barbosa Sampaio';
            $this->need_instance = 0;
            $this->ps_versions_compliancy = [
                'min' => '1.7.0.0',
                'max' => '8.99.99',
            ];
            $this->bootstrap = true;

            parent::__construct();

            $this->displayName = $this->l('cpf');
            $this->description = $this->l('Descrição do meu módulo.');
            $this->confirmUninstall = $this->l('Tem certeza de que deseja desinstalar?');
}

public function install(){
    if(!parent::install() ||
        !$this->registerHook('leftColumn') ||
        !$this->registerHook('header') ||
        !$this->registerHook('additionalCustomerFormFields')||
        !Configuration::updateValue('cpf', 'my friend')){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
public function uninstall(){
    if (!parent::uninstall() ||
        !Configuration::deleteByName('cpf')
    ) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
public function hookAdditionalCustomerFormFields($params){
    $extra_fields = array();
    $extra_fields['cpf'] = (new FormField)
        ->setName('cpf')
        ->setType('text')
        ->setLabel($this->l('CPF'))
        ->setRequired(true);

    return $extra_fields;
}
public function hookvalidateCustomerFormFields($params){
    echo "method called teste brasileiro";
    $module_fields = $params['fields'];
    $cpf = $module_fields['cpf']->getValue();
    error_log('CPF value: '.$cpf);
    // Adicione aqui a validação para o campo CPF
    if (empty($cpf)) {
        $module_fields['cpf']->addError($this->l('O campo CPF é obrigatório.'));
    } elseif (!preg_match('/^\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}-\d{2}$/', $cpf)) {
        $module_fields['cpf']->addError($this->l('O formato do CPF é inválido.'));
    }else{
        $id_customer = (int)$params['newCustomer']->id;
        $sql = 'UPDATE `'._DB_PREFIX_.'customer` SET `cpf` = \''.pSQL($cpf).'\' WHERE `id_customer` = '.$id_customer;
        error_log('SQL query: '.$sql);
        
        Db::getInstance()->execute($sql);
    }
    return $module_fields;
}
}

?>
```

v2 using the documentation:

```
<?php 
if(!defined('_PS_VERSION_')){
    exit;
}


class Cpf extends Module{
    public function __construct(){
        
        $this->name = 'Cpf module';
        $this->tab = 'front_office_features';
        $this->version = '1.4.0';
        $this->author = 'Henrique Barbosa Sampaio';
        $this->need_instance = 1;
        $this->ps_versions_compliancy = [
            'min' => '1.7.0.0',
            'max' => '8.99.99',
        ];
        $this->bootstrap = true;
        
        $this->bootstrap = true;
        $this->displayName = $this->l('Modulo cpf');
        $this->description = $this->l('modulo para adicionar o campo cpf no prestashop futuramente tera um check de cpf e uma estruturação mais bem feita.');

        $this->confirmUninstall = $this->l('Are you sure you want to uninstall?');

        if (!Configuration::get('Cpf')) {
            $this->warning = $this->l('Se nome provido');
        }
    }
    
        public function install()
    {
        if (Shop::isFeatureActive()) {
        Shop::setContext(Shop::CONTEXT_ALL);
        }

        return parent::install() &&
        $this->registerHook('displayLeftColumn') &&
        $this->registerHook('actionFrontControllerSetMedia') &&
        $this->registerHook('displayRightColumn') &&
        Configuration::updateValue('Cpf', 'my module');
    }
    
}





?>
```